# Rollbar and Rails: No route matches [GET] "/blog/wp-login.php"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently installed Rollbar on my to-be Production instance and I see that Rollbar has starting reporting this issue about not finding a WordPress login.

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/blog/wp-login.php"
```

I searched through all my code and dont find any references wp-login.php and the stack trace is not helping either. Would you know where this might be coming from?

```
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb" line 21 in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rollbar-2.7.1/lib/rollbar/middleware/rails/show_exceptions.rb" line 22 in call_with_rollbar
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb" line 30 in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb" line 38 in call_app
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb" line 20 in block in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb" line 68 in block in tagged
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb" line 26 in tagged
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb" line 68 in tagged
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb" line 20 in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb" line 21 in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb" line 21 in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb" line 17 in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb" line 84 in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/send.rb" line 112 in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/engine.rb" line 511 in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application.rb" line 97 in call
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb" line 30 in method_missing
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb" line 562 in process_client
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb" line 658 in worker_loop
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb" line 508 in spawn_missing_workers
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb" line 132 in start
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn" line 126 in <top (required)>
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn" line 23 in load
"/home/myproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn" line 23 in <main>
```

Comment: people are fishing around looking for unpatched versions of wordpress to  exploit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is just the random background noise of the internet - scripts wander around looking for known security holes (in this case, one in WordPress) that their human might want to exploit. If someone ever puts your link into an MS Office document, you'll also see weird `OPTIONS` requests.

It's common to configure error reporting to ignore `RoutingError`s, though of course there are pros and cons to that. It lets you ignore this noise, which can trigger false alarms, but if you ever actually render a bad URL, it can go unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks! I will just ignore these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore them, you can configure your Rollbar like this:

```
config.exception_level_filters.merge!("ActionController::RoutingError" => lambda do |e|
    # Ignore /*.php, /*.xml, *.yml, .txt because they're just probing for security holes
    e.message.match(/No route matches \[GET\] "\/.*\.(php|xml|yml|txt)"/) ? "ignore" : "warning"
  end)
```

I chose to ignore any php, xml, yml or txt GET. You might also want to look at ignoring others, depending on what you're seeing in your logs. The .php is 80% of it for me though.